# SELECT * Within a join

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use `*`when using `JOIN`.  I so far have the following result using

```
SELECT * FROM default_ps_products_categories INNER JOIN default_ps_products_brand_by_cat
```

but I am wanting it to return one of each and not two as shown - Do I have to do the query correctly and select the tables?. The two coloumns that match are `id` and `cat_id`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `ON` clause in the join, in which case MySQL returns a full Cartesian join instead of complaining.

Try (I'm using aliases because the table names are long):

```
SELECT * 
FROM default_ps_products_categories C
INNER JOIN default_ps_products_brand_by_cat B ON C.id = B.cat_id
```

*Note: The `*` is fine and is not the source of your problem.*

Comment: +1 for your answer and use of the word "Cartesian"!  That being said, I recommend never using * in your SELECT statements when used in an application other than for testing (and several other very rare applications).

Comment: @user1032531 Agreed with the *, it most often leads to trouble, and doesn't do anything but save typing out a few more characters